# Highcharts height issue - remove white space at the top. See JSFiddle :)

Tags: highcharts

[See JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mschreiberjdi/dk0zgk09/)

I want to remove the white space at the top of the highchart, and move the chart to the top of the page and even with the legend on the right hand side.

What's the best way to remove this empty space and/or change the height of the chart?

Thanks

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBackgroundImage: null,
      plotBorderWidth: 0,
      plotShadow: false,
      backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Probability of Success<br>Current Plan<br>',
      align: 'center',
      verticalAlign: 'bottom',
      y: -70
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Within Confidence Zone',
      align: 'center',
      verticalAlign: 'bottom',
      y: -30
    },
    pane: {
      center: ['50%','95%'],
      size: '80%',
      startAngle: -90,
      endAngle: 90,
      background: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        innerRadius: '90%',
        outerRadius: '100%',
        shape: 'arc'
      }
    },
    yAxis: [
      {
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 90,
        minorTickLength: 0,
        tickLength: 0,
        tickWidth: 0,
        labels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        title: {
          text: '',
          useHTML: true,
          y: 80
        },
        pane: 0
      }
    ],
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        enableMouseTracking: false
      },
      pie: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          distance: 0,
          style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: 'white',
            textShadow: '0px 1px 2px black'
          }
        },
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        center: ['50%', '100%']
      },
      gauge: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        pivot: {
          radius: 125,
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderColor: 'transparent',
          backgroundColor: 'white'
        },
        dial: {
          radius: '100%',
          backgroundColor: 'gray',
          borderColor: 'gray',
          baseWidth: 140,
          topWidth: 1,
          baseLength: '5%', // of radius
          rearLength: '5%'
        }
      }
    },

    series: [{
      "type": "pie",
      "name": "Risk",
      "innerSize": "85%",
      "data": [{
        "y": 40,
        "name": "",
        "color": "#c5e3f0"
      }, {
        "y": 30,
        "name": "",
        "color": "#80c3e0"
      }, {
        "y": 30,
        "name": "",
        "color": "#037dae"
      }]
    }, {
      type: 'gauge',
      name: 'Success',
      data: [25],
      dial: {
        rearLength: 0
      }
    }],
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I helped you with this same chart yesterday!  Welcome back.

**[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kas5a6hr/)**

There are several key items that govern the placement of elements in this kind of chart.

`plotOptions.pie.center` should be `['50%', '47%']`

`pane.center` should be `['50%', '47%']`

Adjust the second number (the y value) to nudge it a little higher or lower.

Then change your title/subtitle locations like this:

```
title: {
    text: 'Probability of Success<br>Current Plan<br>',
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 145
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'Within Confidence Zone',
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 187
},
```

Again, you're just changing the `y` values.  Notice that I also changed the `verticalAlign` to `top` instead of `bottom` to get better control over it.

And finally, you'll want to set the height of your `<div>` container and set it to clip any extra whitespace content:

```
<div id="container" style="height: 186px; overflow: hidden" class="left-col" ></div>
```

See the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kas5a6hr/) for final results.

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

Move Chart To The Top and get rid of this white space
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="container" style="height: 186px; overflow: hidden" class="left-col"></div>
</div>
```

**CODE**

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      height: 400,
      renderTo: 'container',
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBackgroundImage: null,
      plotBorderWidth: 0,
      plotShadow: false,
      backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Probability of Success<br>Current Plan<br>',
      align: 'center',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      y: 125
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Within Confidence Zone',
      align: 'center',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      y: 166
    },
    pane: {
      center: ['50%', '47%'],
      size: '80%',
      startAngle: -90,
      endAngle: 90,
      background: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        innerRadius: '90%',
        outerRadius: '100%',
        shape: 'arc'
      }
    },
    yAxis: [{
      lineWidth: 0,
      min: 0,
      max: 90,
      minorTickLength: 0,
      tickLength: 0,
      tickWidth: 0,
      labels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      title: {
        text: '',
        useHTML: true,
        y: 80
      },
      pane: 0
    }],
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        enableMouseTracking: false
      },
      pie: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          distance: 0,
          style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: 'white',
            textShadow: '0px 1px 2px black'
          }
        },
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        center: ['50%', '47%']
      },
      gauge: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        pivot: {
          radius: 125,
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderColor: 'transparent',
          backgroundColor: 'white'
        },
        dial: {
          radius: '100%',
          backgroundColor: 'gray',
          borderColor: 'gray',
          baseWidth: 140,
          topWidth: 1,
          baseLength: '5%', // of radius
          rearLength: '5%'
        }
      }
    },

    series: [{
      "type": "pie",
      "name": "Risk",
      "innerSize": "85%",
      "data": [{
        "y": 40,
        "name": "",
        "color": "#c5e3f0"
      }, {
        "y": 30,
        "name": "",
        "color": "#80c3e0"
      }, {
        "y": 30,
        "name": "",
        "color": "#037dae"
      }]
    }, {
      type: 'gauge',
      name: 'Success',
      data: [25],
      dial: {
        rearLength: 0
      }
    }],
  });
});
```

Comment: Question:  When I resize your fiddle below 375 the chart disappears.  How can we make the chart responsive so that it will shrink and fill the space under 375?  Here is your fiddler showing the chart disappear.  Thanks https://jsfiddle.net/kas5a6hr/show